# Using field calculation with vb?

Tags: vbscript, vb

Could you please help with the code below.

```
dim n
if [Flow] <200 then
n = -(16.6*Log (30/10.112))*Log ( [Flow] /200)))^2)) else
elseif [Flow] > 4000 then
n = 42.2+10*(LOG [Flow]) +(33*(LOG( [18_ffspeed]+40+(500/ [18_ffspeed]))))+
(10*(LOG(1+((5* [18_hgvprop])/ [18_ffspeed] ))))-68.8
end if
```

the codeblock is

```
BNL = n
```

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Field Calculator?  What happens when you run your code?  What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [tour]  to better understand how things work here.  Please [edit] the question to specify the **exact** version of GIS software in use and the exact error  message(s) generated by your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Your code syntax is incorrect, you have an extra else in it, so your code block should be this:

```vb
dim n
if [Flow] <200 then
    n = -(16.6*Log (30/10.112))*Log ( [Flow] /200)))^2))
elseif [Flow] > 4000 then
    n = 42.2+10*(LOG [Flow]) +(33*(LOG( [18_ffspeed]+40+(500/ [18_ffspeed]))))+(10*(LOG(1+((5* [18_hgvprop])/ [18_ffspeed] ))))-68.8
end if
```